# error: reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length?

Tags: java

```java
        if (!jtfIdEmp.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfNombre.getText().isEmpty() &&
                !jtfApellidos.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfSexo.getText().isEmpty()
                && !jtfFechaNaci.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfDireccion.getText().isEmpty()
                && !jtfColonia.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfMunicipio.getText().isEmpty()
                && !jtfCp.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfTelefono.getText().isEmpty()
                && !jtfPuesto.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfUsuario.getText().isEmpty()
                && !jtfContrasena.getText().isEmpty() && !jtfIdLab.getText().isEmpty()){
        
        user = new Empleado(jtfIdEmp.getText(), jtfNombre.getText(),
                jtfApellidos.getText(), jtfSexo.getText(), jtfFechaNaci.getText()
                jtfDireccion.getText(), jtfColonia.getText(), jtfMunicipio.getText(),
                jtfCp.getText(), jtfTelefono.getText(), jtfPuesto.getText(), 
                jtfUsuario.getText(), jtfContrasena.getText(), jtfIdLab.getText());
```

```
 //constructor Empleado in class Empleado cannot be applied to given types:
required: no arguments
found: String,String,String.String,String
reason: actaul and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Hola!, te encuentras en SO español, sería genial que cambies el título por algo más descriptivo y en español, también añade detalles del error, que intentas hacer por ejemplo, además el error indica que los parámetros que estás pasando al constructor de Empleado no son los correctos, puedes compartir tu clase Empleado también?

Comment: El error se traduce solo, esta tratando de crear un Empleado con una cantidad diferente de argumentos, es decir, puede que el constructor tenga 5 parametros pero usted esta pasando 6 o 4, adicional a esto debe tener en cuenta el tipo de dato del parametro, estos deben ir en el orden que se solicitan.

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo tu error se debe a que tu solo declaraste un constructor de la clase Empleado sin argumentos

```
public Empleado() {
    }
```

Para que tu código no te genere este error debes declarar el constructor de tu clase con los parametros A continuación te presento un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo.

```
public class Empleado {
    
    String idEmp;
    String Nombre;
    String Apellidos;
    String Sexo;
    String FechaNaci;
    String Direccion;
    String Colonia;
    String Municipio;
    String Cp;
    String Telefono;
    String Puesto;
    String Usuario;
    String Contrasena;
    String IdLab;

    public Empleado(String idEmp, String Nombre, String Apellidos, String Sexo, String FechaNaci, String Direccion, String Colonia, String Municipio, String Cp, String Telefono, String Puesto, String Usuario, String Contrasena, String IdLab) {
        this.idEmp = idEmp;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.Apellidos = Apellidos;
        this.Sexo = Sexo;
        this.FechaNaci = FechaNaci;
        this.Direccion = Direccion;
        this.Colonia = Colonia;
        this.Municipio = Municipio;
        this.Cp = Cp;
        this.Telefono = Telefono;
        this.Puesto = Puesto;
        this.Usuario = Usuario;
        this.Contrasena = Contrasena;
        this.IdLab = IdLab;
    }
```

También veo que tienes un error al pasar los argumentos te falta una coma después  de jtfFechaNaci.getText() por eso en la linea

```
found: String,String,String.String,String
```

solo detecta 5 Strings. Así debería quedar tu instancia de la clase Empleado

```
user = new Empleado(jtfIdEmp.getText(), jtfNombre.getText(),
                jtfApellidos.getText(), jtfSexo.getText(), jtfFechaNaci.getText(),
                jtfDireccion.getText(), jtfColonia.getText(), jtfMunicipio.getText(),
                jtfCp.getText(), jtfTelefono.getText(), jtfPuesto.getText(), 
                jtfUsuario.getText(), jtfContrasena.getText(), jtfIdLab.getText());
```

Espero haberte ayudado.